# How can I get a particular part of a String enclosed between 2 characters using Excel VBA?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to write a macro in excel which can help me get a particular part of a string. My string is as follows :

PAYPAL *VINAYAKAGGRAWAL 4029357733

I need to extract VINAYAKAGGRAWAL from the above string. Any help with vba macro or any excel formula to do this would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So many ways to achieve this. What is it you have tried yourself? You tagged `regex` but it doesn't look needed with the sample you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two characters are "*" and " " as in the string above, then you could use this in VBA:

```
Function GetString(s As String) As String
    GetString = Split(Split(s, "*")(1), " ")(0)
End Function
```

Or use an in-cell formulae on the worksheet:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(D8,LEN(D8)-FIND("*",D8)),FIND(" ",RIGHT(D8,LEN(D8)-FIND("*",D8)))))
```

where `D8` would have the original string in

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub parser()
    Dim s As String, s2 As String, s3 As String
    s = "PAYPAL *VINAYAKAGGRAWAL 4029357733"
    s2 = Mid(s, InStr(1, s, "*") + 1)
    s3 = Left(s2, InStr(1, s2, " "))
    MsgBox s3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
strClean = Replace("PAYPAL *VINAYAKAGGRAWAL 4029357733", "PAYPAL *", "")
strWanted = Left(strClean, InStr(strClean, " ") - 1)
Debug.Print strWanted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strClean = Split(Replace("PAYPAL *VINAYAKAGGRAWAL 4029357733", "*", ""))(1)
```

### How it works:

1. First, we get rid of the `*` character with `Replace` function - change it to empty string.
2. Then we split the string by the space with `Split` function. We don't mention the space delimiter explicitly, because it's a default delimiter for `Split`.
3. Finally, we get the second item from the string with `(1)`. `Split` returns zero-based array, so that first item is `(0)`, second is `(1)` etc. Since we need second item, we use `(1)`.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @SherylHohman I have added explanation. 